# C: Shell program receiving anomolous extra operands

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal, execvp

I am creating my own shell in C using `fork` and `execvp`. I am parsing the cmd and it's arguments using `strtok`. Printing the parsed tokens confirms to me that I am indeed receiving all the arguments, and the shell generally works, though it is very basic of course because I am quite a noob. However, here are two typical scenarios when I run the shell which are baffling me, notice how the `ls` and `pwd` commands work the first time, but then begin to get these extra operands from somewhere:

```
➜  a2 ./shell
(user)># pwd

/home/user/ClionProjects/unix_programming/a2
(user)># ls -la

total 32
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 Mar  9 13:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 user user  4096 Mar  6 14:18 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 13616 Mar  9 13:18 shell
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3809 Mar  9 13:17 shell.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   545 Mar  9 12:58 shell.h
(user)># pwd

pwd: ignoring non-option arguments
/home/user/ClionProjects/unix_programming/a2
(user)>#
```

**AND**

```
➜  a2 ./shell
(user)># pwd

/home/user/ClionProjects/unix_programming/a2
(user)># ls -la

total 32
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 Mar  9 13:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 user user  4096 Mar  6 14:18 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 13616 Mar  9 13:18 shell
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3809 Mar  9 13:17 shell.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   545 Mar  9 12:58 shell.h
(user)># pwd

pwd: ignoring non-option arguments
/home/user/ClionProjects/unix_programming/a2
(user)>#
```

In the code below you can see that I store the arguments in `tokens`. The first token being the cmd filename itself.

I have tried `memset`ting `tokens` to all zeros, `free`ing it and re-`malloc`ing it at the start of each iteration of the while loop. I have tried always resizing `tokens` to the number of args currently in it. I have done these things because I have become convinced that somehow, `tokens` is retaining content from previous commands that are for some reason being read by later commands. However, re-`malloc`ing and `realloc`ing `tokens` has not touched the problem, so I am now at a loss. Any advice or nudges in the right direction much appreciated.

**shell.h**

```
#ifndef UNIX_PROGRAMMING_SHELL_H
#define UNIX_PROGRAMMING_SHELL_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>

int sig_int = 0;

void signal_handler(int sig_num);
void start_shell();
void prompt();
void change_dir(char *path, pid_t *pid, int *status);
void execute_cmd(const char *file_name, char *const *args);
void parse_cmd(char *cmd, char **tokens, size_t *index);

#endif //UNIX_PROGRAMMING_SHELL_H
```

**shell.c**

```
#include "shell.h"


void signal_handler(int sig_num) {
    printf("\n"); // Do nothing when Ctrl-C is pressed
}

void prompt() {
    /* Get current users username and display prompt */
    char *user = getlogin();
    printf("(%s)># ", (user==NULL)? "": user);
}

void change_dir(char *path, pid_t *pid, int *status) {
    *pid = fork();

    if (*pid == -1) {
        printf("Error changing directory..\n");
    } else if (*pid == 0) {
        chdir(path);
    } else {
        *pid = wait(status);

        if (*pid == -1) {
            printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
            return;
        }
    }
}

void execute_cmd(const char *file_name, char *const *args) {
    execvp(file_name, args);
}

/** parse commands into tokens... **/
void parse_cmd(char *cmd, char **tokens, size_t *index) {
    char *tok;
    const char *delim = " ";
    *index = 0;

    // TODO: realloc tokens, so it can start from 2 and build up as needed
    tok = strtok(cmd, delim);
    if (tok != NULL) {
        tokens[*index] = tok;
        (*index)++;
    } else {
        tokens[*index] = "\0";
        return;
    }

    while ((tok = strtok(NULL, delim)) != NULL) {
        tokens[*index] = tok;
        (*index)++;
    }
//    for (size_t i = 0; i < *index; i++) {
//        printf("arg[%zu]: %s\n", i, tokens[i]);
//    }
    printf("\n");
}

void start_shell() {
    ssize_t c;
    size_t cmd_size = 20;
    size_t num_args = 5;
    int *status = NULL;
    pid_t pid;

    char *cmd = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));                    /* command line input */
    char **tokens = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_args);  /* command line input parsed into tokens */
    size_t *index = (size_t *) malloc(sizeof(size_t));            /* number of tokens parsed */

    if (tokens == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Out of memory..");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    prompt();

    /* main loop - get input, parse, process - until termination */
    while ( (c = getline(&cmd, &cmd_size, stdin)) != EOF ) {

        cmd[strcspn(cmd, "\n")] = '\0';  /* trim newline */
        parse_cmd(cmd, tokens, index);

        /* resize tokens to fit only it's current contents */
//        if (*index < num_args && *index != 0 && *index != 1) {
        tokens = realloc(tokens, *index);
//        }

        const char *file_name = tokens[0];
        char *const *args = tokens;

        /* If command is blank */
        if ( (c = strcspn(file_name, "\n\r\0") == 0) ) {
            tokens[0] = "\0";
            prompt();
            continue;

        } else if ( (c = strcmp(file_name, "exit")) == 0 ) {
            break;

        } else if ( (c = strcmp(file_name, "cd")) == 0 ) {

            if (*index == 1) { /* no path provided */
                chdir(getenv("HOME"));
            } else {
                char *path = realpath(args[1], NULL);
                if (path == NULL) {
                    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
                    break;
                } else {
                    change_dir(path, &pid, status);
                }
            }
        }

        // fork here ... success: parent < pid .. child << 0 -- failure: parent << -1
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {
            printf("Error executing command\n");
            continue;
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            execute_cmd(file_name, args);
        } else {

            pid = wait(status);
            if (pid == -1) {
                printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        tokens[0] = "\0";
        prompt();
    }

    free(cmd);
    free(tokens);
    free(index);
    printf("\n"); /* avoids unwanted terminal output for ctrl-D */
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    start_shell();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR but you have to `NULL` terminate argument lists passed to `execvp`, this is probably the issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, I will check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execvp` needs that argument list to be `NULL` terminated (else it cannot tell the argument count)

You're not adding `NULL` when you're building your command. So that's undefined behaviour, and an extra ghost args or two are passed to `execvp` (until it finally finds a `NULL` or just a good old *segfault*)

so:

```
char **tokens = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_args);  /* command line input parsed into tokens */
```

should be

```
char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (num_args + 1));  /* command line input parsed into tokens */
```

and in `parse_cmd` add the `NULL` item:

```
while ((tok = strtok(NULL, delim)) != NULL) {
    tokens[*index] = tok;
    (*index)++;
}  // this is your code, now
tokens[*index] = NULL;
(*index)++; // maybe not necessary
```

now `execvp` is passed a `NULL` terminated string.

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed it.